# How to run the select Query here?

Tags: sql, time, range

This is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_djr 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND djr_date_of_work >='12/31/2012'  
    AND djr_date_of_work<='01/06/2013' 
ORDER BY djr_id
```

date format = m/d/Y

here is my table

```
djr_date_of_work    djr_client_name       
01/03/2013              Maitland CC     
01/07/2013              kokil CC 
01/01/2013              Maitland CC 
01/04/2013              Maitland CC
```

Comment: At least as stated, there's no `djr_id` column anywhere.

Comment: Don't use date formats like `m/d/Y` for storing data. Use a general-purpose date format, otherwise you won't be able to sort them or use range queries (as you want to do). You should only use `m/d/Y` for displaying the output to the user, not for the actual database.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
 FROM tbl_djr 
 WHERE 1=1 
  AND djr_date_of_work >='12/31/2012'  
  AND djr_date_of_work<='01/06/2013' 
ORDER BY djr_id
```

The above Query won't work because you used and condition means .

it should satisfy both djr_date_of_work >='12/31/2012' AND djr_date_of_work<='01/06/2013' for same condition

Try the below query

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tbl_djr 
 WHERE 1=1 
  AND djr_date_of_Work between '12/31/2012'   and '01/06/2013' 
ORDER BY djr_id
```

If your djr_date_of_Work is date column try below

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tbl_djr 
 WHERE 1=1 
  AND djr_date_of_Work between TO_DATE('12/31/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') and TO_DATE('01/06/2013','DD/MM/YYYY') 
ORDER BY djr_id
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e3be/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_djr  
    (djr_id int,[djr_date_of_work] datetime, [djr_client_name] varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO tbl_djr  
    ([djr_id],[djr_date_of_work], [djr_client_name])
VALUES
    (1,'01/03/2013', 'Maitland CC'),
    (2,'01/07/2013', 'kokil CC'),
    (3,'01/01/2013', 'Maitland CC'),
    (4,'01/04/2013', 'Maitland CC')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT djr_id,convert(varchar(10), djr_date_of_work, 101),djr_client_name
FROM tbl_djr
WHERE djr_date_of_work BETWEEN '12/31/2012'
    AND '01/06/2013'
ORDER BY djr_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e3be/1/0)**:

```
| DJR_ID |   COLUMN_1 | DJR_CLIENT_NAME |
-----------------------------------------
|      1 | 01/03/2013 |     Maitland CC |
|      3 | 01/01/2013 |     Maitland CC |
|      4 | 01/04/2013 |     Maitland CC |
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the exception / underlying issue this is difficult to diagnose, however as someone pointed out in the comments there is no `djr_id` column, so your query cannot execute.  Further the statement:

`where 1=1`

is useless as that will always evaluate to true.

What you want is to modify your schema like so:

```
alter table tbl_djr add column djr_id as number
```

Syntax varies on your database, but the pseudocode will get you started.  Your final query should look like this:

```
select * from tbl_djr where djr_date_of_Work between '12/31/2012'   
and '01/06/2013' order by djr_id
```

As a point of style this name:
`tbl_djr` provides no information as it is known that `djr` would be a table.  Further all table names are supposed to be plural names, such as `djrs`

Comment: im using mysql ..... it has thousands of rows i think its impossible to change ... its have date query if i change i need change alll i think ....